# Combine Columns from Another Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm very new to using Google Sheets, and I'm trying to create a sheet that pulls data from my form submissions.

The form submissions go into Shift Report and I have two outcomes depending on product. Broadband Outcome and Voice Outcome. I need both submissions for these two outcomes to go into a column together on another sheet. I have tried multiple things in regards to query and concatenate but I can't seem to get it to work.

Any help will be much apreciated.

In summary:

Sheet 1 = Shift Report

Sheet 2 = Annual Data

I need columns K and U from Shift Report to go into column J in Annual Data

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications Stack Exchange. I'm glad that you got an answer very quickly, and apparently, it was satisfactory to you as it shows as **accepted**. However, this question is not a very good fit for this site.  Please bear in mind that this site is not a help/service desk. You could [edit] the question to make it a better fit by including a description of your spreadsheet, sample input data, the expected result, what you have tried a brief description about similar questions from this site and why they don't meet your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly how do you expect your outcome to be, but you can try with things like these:

```
={'Shift Report'!K:K} to grab an entire column
=ARRAYFORMULA('Shift Report'!K:K&'Shift Report'!U:U) If you need to concatenate in one column both values. If you need to add a separator you can put it in between:
=ARRAYFORMULA('Shift Report'!K:K&" - "&'Shift Report'!U:U)
```